# Clicking multiple checkboxes with one using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onchange

I am trying to check multiple sub-checkboxes when I check a header-checkbox. My code is in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepd/sF3My/8/).

My code is:

```
$('input.fieldCheck'.on('change', function(event) {
var $rows = $(this).parents('tr.field').nextUntil('tr.field');
var isChecked = this.checked;
$rows.each(function() {
    $(this).find('input.subFieldCheck').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked', isChecked);
    });});        
}));
```

What is wrong with this?

Thank you

Comment: try this - `var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked")`

Comment: `$('input.fieldCheck'` <- forgot `)` here

Answer (score 2):

There are three main issues causing this to not work.

1 - `$('input.fieldCheck'.on('change',` is missing the closing `)`

2 - You were trying to follow a naming pattern called `lower camel case`, unfortunately, you missed it; because every `input.subFieldCheck` should be `input.subfieldCheck`, notice how you missed the LCC pattern on the word `field` here.

3 - There's also an extra `)` at the closing of the `on('change')` event. Also removed in the fiddle.

4 - [Here's your working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJ4sA/) (cleaned up some errors in your HTML markup as well)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (with a nice long jQuery chain and no assignments) :

```
$('input.fieldCheck').on('change', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('tr.field').nextUntil('tr.field').find('input.subfieldCheck').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sF3My/10/)**